# Cite authors or inform the reader that these guys made it?

Tags: formality, research

I writing a research paper in which I want to say that Paul Viola and Michael Jones (authors behind a framework) made this framework.

What is the more formal way of saying this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is academic writing - you may want to make propert citations and as I know under "Credits:" you could use work "Creator/Author Framework".

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the format your course impose. If you use MLA, you can intext citation follows the format (Author surname, page number), assuming of course you are quoting a book. More details [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/05/)

APA on the other hand follows the format (Author surname, year published) for intext citation. More details [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/)